# Symfony 2 - turn off translations in Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, translation, sonata-admin, sonata

I would like to:

- modify flash messages (not displaying entity names every time I update or delete entity)
- rename some more labels that I can find in translation files

In this case I could just overwrite `SonataAdminBundle.en.xliff`, but I should also do it for other languages too.

Is there a possibility to turn off all the translations for Sonata Admin except english, so no matter the locale in the request object, my administration page would be translated in english only?

**UPDATE**

Just a thought. Maybe to write an event listener that detect admin routes and sets locale always to `en`?